# Reactjs sort function gets sorted after few clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a Reactjs app. I'm having trouble with the sort function. It appears to be working, but you'll need to click sort a few times to get it properly sorted. I tried almost everything; I assumed from the start that the numbers in the strings were causing the problem, so I used `parseInt`, but it didn't help. Please advise on what might be causing this problem. Thank you

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([
    {
      id: 3,
      color: "red",
      value: "#f00",
      position: 1000
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      color: "green",
      value: "#0f0",
      position: 0
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      color: "blue",
      value: "#00f",
      position: 5
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      color: "cyan",
      value: "#0ff",
      position: 1010
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      color: "magenta",
      value: "#f0f",
      position: 3001
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      color: "yellow",
      value: "#ff0",
      position: 70
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      color: "black",
      value: "#000",
      position: 1000
    }
  ]);
  const [asc, setAsc] = useState(true);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(4);

  useEffect(() => {
    let argArray = ["id", "color", "value", "position"];
    setArray(
      array &&
        array.sort((a, b) =>
          asc
            ? a[argArray[filter]] - b[argArray[filter]]
            : b[argArray[filter]] - a[argArray[filter]]
        )
    );
  }, [asc, filter, array]);

  const sets = (filter, isAscending) => {
    setFilter(filter);
    setAsc(isAscending);
    console.log("sets Function", filter, isAscending);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sort Function</h1>
      <h2>Sort function debugging!</h2>
      <div className="array-wrapper">
        <div className="array-elements-wrapper heading">
          <div
            className={filter === 0 ? "active asc-" + asc : ""}
            onClick={() => sets(0, !asc)}
          >
            ID
          </div>
          <div
            className={filter === 1 ? "active asc-" + asc : ""}
            onClick={() => sets(1, !asc)}
          >
            Color
          </div>
          <div
            className={filter === 2 ? "active asc-" + asc : ""}
            onClick={() => sets(2, !asc)}
          >
            Value
          </div>
          <div
            className={filter === 3 ? "active asc-" + asc : ""}
            onClick={() => sets(3, !asc)}
          >
            Position
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        {array.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="array-elements-wrapper">
            <div>{item.id}</div>
            <div>{item.color}</div>
            <div>{item.value}</div>
            <div>{item.position}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.array-wrapper {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border: darkgray;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.array-elements-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.array-elements-wrapper div {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  text-align: left;
}
.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.heading div:hover {
  color: #444444;
}
.heading div:active {
  color: chocolate;
}
.active {
  color: darkviolet;
  position: relative;
}
.asc-false:before {
  content: "↑";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
}
.asc-true:before {
  content: "↓";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-[US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the original array, so you're probably missing re-renders since the array reference has not changed. Try `[...array].sort(yourCode..`

Comment: Thank you Brian,  `[...array]` helped it